# Kanex Thunderbolt 2 Express Dock

Tags: thunderbolt

I am using the following setup:
Dell XPS-15-9550 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Dell XPS 15" Notebook Ubuntu 16.04 LTS --> USB-C/Thunderbolt3 to
Thunderbolt 2 Adapter from Kanex --> Kanex Thunderbolt 2 Express Dock --> Apple Thunderbolt Display

So far the Apple Display works fine. But from the Kanex Dock I only see

`06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1576
07:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1576
07:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1576
07:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1576
08:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 1575`

but nothing "behind" like the ethernet-port or usb-ports. also from the Apple Display (this works fine !) I can not see any of the ports (no ethernet,usb,firewire).
Any idea how to start to get this things to work ? I would also write a drive as soon some could give me a starting-point (documentation,hints...).
Any kind of help would be fine !

Martin

Answer (score 1):

i have an OWC thunderbolt dock attached to my dell precision m3800 (which is mostly the same as yours) via its thunderbolt 2 interface. I just plugged it in and it worked.

Thunderbolt is hot plug pci which has been in the linux kernel for some time (2.6 i think) as its used by some big storage systems , however accessing it via a usbc port is new.

heres my lspci with the dock

```
 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
 00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
 00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 0c03 (rev 06)
 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
 00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
 00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
 00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
 00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
 00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
 00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
 00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
 00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller (rev 05)
 02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] (rev ff)
 06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)
 07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
 08:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 157e
 09:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 157e
 09:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 157e
 0a:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 157d
 0b:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
 0c:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
 0c:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
 0c:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
 0c:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
 0c:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
 0c:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
 0d:00.0 USB controller: Fresco Logic FL1100 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 10)
 0e:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
 0f:00.0 USB controller: Fresco Logic FL1100 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 10)
 10:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): LSI Corporation FW643 [TrueFire] PCIe 1394b Controller (rev 08)
```

Your kernel will enable the usb c port if it has the drivers for it , if so it will appear in the output of this command

```
lspci -d ::0c03 -k
```

try newer kernels until you find one that can enable it, the intel chipsets should be fully supported in the upstream kernel but seem not to have made it to the ubuntu ones.

There should be entries in your logs related to attempts to enable the port, please post them here.

Update:

in theory you should be able to run the following command to rescan the pci bus which might help to wake up your dock.

```
echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan > /dev/null
```

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is not helpful because you using Thunderbolt 2 and not 3. Yes "Thunderbolt is hot plug pci" - but the APCI table should be able to power on the HW. See: https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/15948.html?mode=reply to get more basic information how this works. So my Thunderbolt 3 PCI Bridge is detected as soon as I plug it in but will not be powered on. So I guess, first step is to change the APCI table for my Ubuntu (?)

Comment: yes 3 is different from 2 but not by much. Does your system show your usb-c port with the lspci command ? i suspect that it will need to be running the usb driver on the port to enable it to power up beyond the most basic usb charging mode.

Comment: the displayport part is distinct from the thunderbolt and doesn't use the pci-e lines that would be used to contact the various controller chips in the dock.

Comment: please add the info to the question not my answer, thanks

Comment: that post details quirks in Apple's implementation of its thunderbolt and acpi configurations , there is no reason to assume the same reason occurs for you running a different OS on different hardware.

Answer (score -2):

really new hardware requires really new software.
this is a good and honest approach.
in this case, thunderbolt is the new technology while your kernel is months old.

prior to try any other *fix*, prior to deeply investigate the issue, upgrade your kernel (latest kernel version is 4.9...)

Comment: The answer is generally correct but it is very short, and the question is 5 months old. In this case it must be useful not only for the person who wrote the question, but for other people, also beginners, so please add details to your answer. Otherwise it might be deleted.

Comment: Sorry this is a guess and I see no knowledge here. Anyway thank you for your effort.

Comment: Yes, I am not an expert, nor a kernel developer neither a Thunderbolt 3 owner but I am a Linux users from long time... Hence my answer comes from experience. I know this is not elegant and you can reject it and disappoint with me (as others have already done) but IMHO this is the starting point of the research to the solution since it is the easiest to try